# Category image not showing on layered navigation URL

Tags: layered-navigation

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Magento 1.8.1.0. I just tested with the default theme, but there's no difference, so I assume it's not theme related.

If I go to a sub-category page via main navigation, e.g. `http://mydomain.ch/maincat/subcat.html`, the category image shows fine, but if I go to the same category via layered navigation Magento adds the sub-category as a GET param, i.e. `http://mydomain.ch/maincat.html?cat=123` and the category image is not showing. The products are showing fine on both URLs, though.

Any ideas if this is a bug or a feature? And if it's a feature the question would be: How to rewrite the latter URL to the first in order to show the category image on both.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug it's a feature :).
Technically when you are on the `maincat.html?cat=123` page, you are still viewing the "maincat" category. The fact that you see only products from the subcategory is a result of an applied filter.
In this case the subcategories don't act like subcategories. They are simple filters just like the others (color, price range, ....).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a workaround for this scenario like rewriting the URL or something?